# How can i get how many times an element from an array exist in another array?

Tags: html, angular

I have a component that calls two functions from a service to get two lists.

I want to check how many times each element from the second list occur in the first one and append the number of occurrences in another array but for some reason whenever i do a console.log I get an empty array

Comment: You must read the documentation for to know how you must any questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Sample code to achieve your requirement. You need to create a function `getFrequency` which takes two arguments and returns its frequency.

```js
let firstList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,2,4];
let secondList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let occurenceList = [];
let countObj ={};
function getFrequency(list,item){
return list.filter(function(value){
    return value === item;
}).length
}

secondList.forEach((item)=>{

    let count = getFrequency(firstList,item);
    
    countObj = {
            "item" :item,
            "count" : count
    };
    
    occurenceList.push(countObj);
});

console.log(occurenceList);
```